# How do I understand the Date inside mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

```
> new Date()
ISODate("2013-07-19T02:38:45.520Z")
> new Date().getDay()
5
>
```

Anyone can tell me why `getDay` returns `5` for `2013-07-19`?

Answer (score 3):

Because '2013-07-19' is a Friday.  From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay):

> Returns the day of the week for the specified date according to local time, where 0 represents Sunday.

Comment: Yes. He wants `.getDate()`.